# Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row

Tags: php, laravel, random, eloquent, fluent

How can I select a random row using Eloquent or Fluent in Laravel framework?

I know that by using SQL, you can do order by RAND(). However, I would like to get the random row **without** doing a count on the number of records prior to the initial query.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no best way to do this without executing at least two queries.

Answer (score 874, accepted):

**Laravel >= 5.2:**

```
User::inRandomOrder()->get();
```

or to get the specific number of records

```
// 5 indicates the number of records
User::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();
// get one random record
User::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

or using the [random](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-random) method for collections:

```
User::all()->random();
User::all()->random(10); // The amount of items you wish to receive
```

Laravel 4.2.7 - 5.1:

```
User::orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
```

Laravel 4.0 - 4.2.6:

```
User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Laravel 3:

```
User::order_by(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Check **[this article](http://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/)** on MySQL random rows. Laravel 5.2 supports this, for older version, there is no better solution then using [RAW Queries](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions).

**edit 1:** As mentioned by Double Gras, orderBy() doesn't allow anything else then ASC or DESC since [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/2aaa601aeb6c5efbef536057c855d8c4dcaf10e0) change. I updated my answer accordingly.

**edit 2:** Laravel 5.2 finally implements [a wrapper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) for this. It's called **inRandomOrder()**.

Comment: Replace 'get' with 'first' if you want a single row.

Comment: for PostgreSQL use `'RANDOM()'`

Comment: Warning: on large datasets this is very slow, adding around 900 ms for me

Comment: This is a depends how the RDBMS implements RAND, on MySQL all rows are fetched and then one is picked. Which is pretty slow on big datasets.

Comment: Can we paginate this?

Comment: You can, however the sorting will be random on every new page. Which makes no sense because it's essentially the same as you press F5.

Comment: yeah , i used `User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();` form my models, is the best for me

Comment: DB::raw('RAND()') slows down the query too much

Comment: Caution, `User::all()->random();` will be slow on large datasets, prefer using `User::inRandomOrder()->get();`. As it will load ALL of your models in a php collection and then pick a random item. You may prefer a database approach without loading all your models.

Comment: DB::.... solution will return you "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found" error so you will have to include DB as "use DB;" above your blablaController class code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there any way to randomised based on specific column. Using inRandomOrder() its randoming based on id. I need to randomised my data based on Zip Code. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 59):

This works just fine,

```
$model=Model::all()->random(1)->first();
```

you can also change argument in random function to get more than one record.

Note: not recommended if you have huge data as this will fetch all rows first and then returns random value.

Comment: A performance-wise downside is that all the records are retrieved.

Comment: here random is called on the collection object not the sql query. the random function is run on php side

Comment: @astroanu Right, but to populate that collection, all rows are queried.

Comment: I could be wrong, but this doesn't seem to work when the parameter passed to the random function is the same as the size of the collection.

Comment: This is not good... This way you are retrieving all records and getting a random one. If your table has too many records this could be bad for your app.

Comment: This one was fine for my needs since I can keep the collection and keep picking random ones (in a seeder)

Answer (score 41):

**tl;dr:** It's nowadays implemented into Laravel, see "edit 3" below.

---

Sadly, as of today there are some caveats with the `->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))` proposed solution:

- It isn't DB-agnostic. e.g. SQLite and PostgreSQL use `RANDOM()`
- Even worse, this solution isn't applicable anymore since [this change](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/2aaa601aeb6c5efbef536057c855d8c4dcaf10e0):

  `$direction = strtolower($direction) == 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc';`

**edit:** Now you can use the [orderByRaw()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw) method: `->orderByRaw('RAND()')`. However this is still not DB-agnostic.

FWIW, CodeIgniter implements a special `RANDOM` sorting direction, which is replaced with the correct grammar when building query. Also it seems to be fairly easy to implement. Looks like we have a candidate for improving Laravel :)

update: here is the [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5223) about this on GitHub, and my pending [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/5435).

**edit 2:** Let's cut the chase. Since Laravel 5.1.18 you can add macros to the query builder:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

Builder::macro('orderByRandom', function () {

    $randomFunctions = [
        'mysql'  => 'RAND()',
        'pgsql'  => 'RANDOM()',
        'sqlite' => 'RANDOM()',
        'sqlsrv' => 'NEWID()',
    ];

    $driver = $this->getConnection()->getDriverName();

    return $this->orderByRaw($randomFunctions[$driver]);
});
```

Usage:

```
User::where('active', 1)->orderByRandom()->limit(10)->get();

DB::table('users')->where('active', 1)->orderByRandom()->limit(10)->get();
```

**edit 3:** Finally! Since Laravel 5.2.33 ([changelog](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/CHANGELOG.md), [PR #13642](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13642)) you can use the native method `inRandomOrder()`:

```
User::where('active', 1)->inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();

DB::table('users')->where('active', 1)->inRandomOrder()->limit(10)->get();
```

Comment: You should change the 5.1 macro name to inRandomOrder so it's forward compatible ;) details, details :)

Comment: That's precisely one thing I did while preparing a 5.1 project before migrating it to 5.2.

Answer (score 30):

**You can use**:

```
ModelName::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Answer (score 25):

it's very simple just check your laravel version

Laravel >= 5.2:

```
User::inRandomOrder()->get();
//or to get the specific number of records
// 5 indicates the number of records
User::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get();
// get one random record
User::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

or using the random method for collections:

```
User::all()->random();
User::all()->random(10); // The amount of items you wish to receive
```

Laravel 4.2.7 - 5.1:

```
 User::orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
```

Laravel 4.0 - 4.2.6:

```
 User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Laravel 3:

```
 User::order_by(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Answer (score 19):

In **Laravel 4 and 5** the `order_by` is replaced by `orderBy`

So, it should be:

```
User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Comment: User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();

Comment: It works thanks, but could you give some information how this works?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What kind of information?

Answer (score 11):

For Laravel 5.2 >=

use the Eloquent method:

```
inRandomOrder()
```

The inRandomOrder method may be used to sort the query results randomly. For example, you may use this method to fetch a random user:

```
$randomUser = DB::table('users')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();
```

from docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: Course::inRandomOrder()->take(20)->get(); Not working for me - bad sort specification

in Find.php line 219

Comment: This one's useful for model factories or db seeding

Answer (score 9):

You can also use order_by method with fluent and eloquent like as:

```
Posts::where_status(1)->order_by(DB::raw(''),DB::raw('RAND()'));
```

This is a little bit weird usage, but works.

Edit: As @Alex said, this usage is cleaner and also works:

```
Posts::where_status(1)->order_by(DB::raw('RAND()'));
```

Comment: this works as well and is a little cleaner..   ->order_by(\DB::raw('RAND()'))

Answer (score 4):

You can easily Use this command:

// Question : name of Model
// take 10 rows from DB In shuffle records...

```
$questions = Question::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: for **ORACLE DB** ```orderByRaw('DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM')```

Answer (score 4):

Use Laravel function

```
ModelName::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also `whereRaw('RAND()')` which does the same, you can then chain `->get()` or `->first()` or even go crazy and add `->paginate(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has a built-in method to shuffle the order of the results.

Here is a quote from the documentation:

```
shuffle()
```

The shuffle method randomly shuffles the items in the collection:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$shuffled = $collection->shuffle();

$shuffled->all();

// [3, 2, 5, 1, 4] - (generated randomly)
```

You can see the [documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-shuffle).

Answer (score 2):

At your model add this:

```
public function scopeRandomize($query, $limit = 3, $exclude = [])
{
    $query = $query->whereRaw('RAND()<(SELECT ((?/COUNT(*))*10) FROM `products`)', [$limit])->orderByRaw('RAND()')->limit($limit);
    if (!empty($exclude)) {
        $query = $query->whereNotIn('id', $exclude);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

then at route/controller

```
$data = YourModel::randomize(8)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to specify first or fail:

```php
$collection = YourModelName::inRandomOrder()
  ->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I get random results in eloquent in one of my projects:

```
$products           =  Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(10);
```

10 - The number of random records to pull.

Comment: you are champion

Answer (score 1):

I have table with thousands of records, so I need something fast. This is my code for pseudo random row:

```
// count all rows with flag active = 1
$count = MyModel::where('active', '=', '1')->count(); 

// get random id
$random_id = rand(1, $count - 1);  

// get first record after random id
$data = MyModel::where('active', '=', '1')->where('id', '>', $random_id)->take(1)->first();
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if there are multiple rows with ids greater than `$count` only the first of these would ever be retrieved, and so it would also be more likely to be retrieved than any other row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code! It Works:

```
  User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).