# How can I select a random entry from a database using Laravel 4's Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model called `Question` linked to a database table named `questions`.

Is there an Eloquent function that will let me take a single random question (or a set number of random questions) from the database? Something like the following:

```
$random_question = Question::takeRandom(1)->get();
```

or

```
$random_questions = Question::takeRandom(5)->get();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply you can do:

```
$random_question = Question::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(1)->get();
```

and

```
$random_question = Question::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(5)->get();
```

If you want to use the syntax as you specified in your question, you can use scopes.
In the model `Question` you can add the following method:

```
public function scopeTakeRandom($query, $size=1)
{
    return $query->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take($size);
}
```

Now you can do `$random_question = Question::takeRandom(1)->get();` and get 1 random question.

You can read more about Laravel 4 query scopes at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Perfect on both fronts. Thank you.

Comment: @SUB0DH Would it work with thousands of records? It won’t slows down app ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = Model::where('id',$id)->get()->random($count);
```

You can use random. It simple and effective.

Comment: This way is good for a few results but if you have thousands of result this method will be slow because it gets first all the results and then it picks a random one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()')) in your query

`$featurep= DB::table('tbl_products')
        ->join('tbl_product_images' , 'tbl_products.ID', '=', 'tbl_product_images.Product_ID')
        ->where(array('tbl_products.is_Active' => 0,'CategoryID' => $result->CategoryID))
        ->groupBy('ID')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
        ->take(4)
        ->get();`