# how get random row laravel-5

Tags: random, eloquent, laravel-5

In L-4 it was simple:

```
$random_quote = Quotation::all()->random(1);
```

But now in L-5 not a single method described in this post is working:
[Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row)

My view file just gets blank.

Comment: What code have you tried ? It works, probably you've missed something

Comment: This is really bad performance-wise, by the way.

Comment: Can you share a performance-wise way? I have c. 30 000 famous sayings in the database...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update for Laravel 5.4

[New randomsorting in Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_inRandomOrder)
`->inRandomOrder()->first()`

Comment: This really helped me, I am having an issue though, I only want a quote and author to show on the page (which is happening) but the id related to each quote is also appearing, how do I exclude the id?

Answer (score 47):

These works but probably you didn't use the right `namespace`, just use the `use` statement at the top of your `class` name like this:

```php
<?php namespace SomeNamespace;

use App\Quotation; // Says "Quotation.php" is in "App" folder (By default in L-5.0)

class someClass {
    //...
}
```

Then you may use in your `method` something like this:

```php
// You may add: use DB; at the top to use DB instead of \DB
$random_quote = Quotation::orderBy(\DB::raw('RAND()'))->first();
```

Or this:

```php
$random_quote = Quotation::orderByRaw("RAND()")->first();
```

Update (Since Laravel - 5.2):

```
$random_quote = Quotation::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Comment: We should put first() instead of get()
I was printing string, and the variable was an array.
That's why the view was blank.

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND()` is actually really slow and I mean really, really, ... , really slow. I start to notice the difference even on a table with 400 rows.

Comment: ::inRandomOrder() resolves to 'ORDER BY RAND()' anyway.

Comment: `$objects = Model::inRandomOrder()->first();` is a cleanest way! Thx.

Answer (score 31):

`random()` gives error in 5.2, so instead u can use `inRandomOrder` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset ,

and it works on Eloquent like

```
Model::inRandomOrder()->first()
```

Comment: Now **THIS** should be the accepted answer. It's not database-specific AND leverages the framework capabilities. +1

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE FOR LARAVEL 5.3

I was happy to discover this is now a native query function! :D

The `inRandomOrder` method may be used to sort the query results randomly. For example, you may use this method to fetch a random user:

```
$randomUser = DB::table('users')
            ->inRandomOrder()
            ->first();
```

---

Unfortunately none of these answers make full use of Laravel 5's collections. If you came here from Google, like me, looking for a completely native solution please look below!

The Answer from The Alpha has the Database dependency flaw and Benjamin's, as he pointed out, may pose a problem when rows are removed in between. Highly unlikely, but still possible.

Here's a a one line solution to select random rows in Laravel 5+

```
// The setup
$numberOfRows = 4;
$models = Model::all(); // or use a ::where()->get();

// And the actual randomisation line
$randRows = $models->shuffle()->slice(0,numberOfRows);
```

Et voila - happy coding! Vote it up when you see it so it'll rise on the page :)

Comment: While this would definitely work, it's excessive to get all results of a table when you only want one row. If you have very large tables, it would slow down performance considerably.

Comment: Just use a ->take(100)?

Comment: Then you would only get a random row of the first 100 rows!

Comment: Alright, fair point! First do a ->count() and then generate a random integer between 1 and $count, then use that for a ::find() - problem solved, right?

Comment: Let's say you have 500 rows. You'd pick a record: mt_rand(1,500), and use find. Quotation::find(15). What if the row with id 15 has been deleted? So you know you have 500 rows, but what you do not know is if there is a record associated with every id between 1 and 500.

Answer (score 12):

The orderByRaw('RAND()') has 2 issues:

1. It's MySQL-server dependant
2. It can be slow on large tables (fetches all rows)

Here is the solution i used, which seems to be a bit better:

```
$cnt = $records->count();
if ($cnt == 0)
    return;

$randIndex = rand(0, $cnt-1);
$obj = $records->skip($randIndex)->take(1)->first();
```

EDIT: Please note that my solution may be a problem (crash if no luck) in case of parrallel requests to the database, if some records are deleted between the "count()" and the "skip()".

Answer (score 8):

I'd implement this a little differently, using [Benjamin's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32221601/1013082). A [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) for this feels appropriate so it's reusable, and it falls into your normal Eloquent use.

**Note:** [In Eloquent 5.2, there is built in support for global scopes.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#global-scopes)

I'm going to create a trait that models can utilize, but you can just add the `scopeRandom` method directly to your specific model.

**/app/GlobalScopes.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait GlobalScopes
{
    public function scopeRandom($query){
        $totalRows = static::count() - 1;
        $skip = $totalRows > 0 ? mt_rand(0, $totalRows) : 0;

        return  $query->skip($skip)->take(1);
    }
}
```

Then, each model you want to utilize the global scopes, name the trait inside the class.

**/app/Quotation.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quotation extends Model
{
    use GlobalScopes;

    //...
}
```

**In use:**

```
$randomQuote = \Quotation::random()->first();
```

Comment: Clever solution and best Laravel specific Answer on this Page.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.1 (and Laravel 5.2) there is a `random` method in the `Collection` class returned by the Eloquent builder.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods

So your call

```
$random_quote = Quotation::all()->random(1);
```

or

```
$random_quote = Quotation::where('column', 'value')->get()->random(1);
```

should work properly.

Comment: `$r = Quotation::all()->random(1);` does work, but it does a `select * from quotations` first which... could be quite slow if there are many Quotations...

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 5.4

1) if need one random model:

```
$object = Model::all()->random();
```

2) if need many random models:

```
$object = Model::all()->random($n); //$n - number of elements
                                    //$object - collection
```

Comment: Calling $collection->random(1) will now return a new collection instance with one item.This method will only return a single object if no arguments are supplied.

Doc ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-random

Comment: This is correct answer from my point of view. The other ones work as well, but even with Laravel 6.x its the documented approach https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections

Answer (score 2):

```
orderByRaw('RAND()')
```

Note: It will take in ram all the rows from the rest of the query, so if you have a large table whithout other filters in the same query it will give bad performances, otherwise this is your option

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`random()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-random) method, which "*returns a random item from the collection*":

```
Product::where('city_id', $discount->product->city)
        ->get()
        ->random(1);
```