# how to select several rows from database(eloquent) order by rand in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i want to select several random rows from database, something like this

```
select * from table order by rand limit 10
```

how to do it in Laravel eloquent model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple than it looks like, you just have to use the suffle() collections method.

The shuffle method randomly shuffles the items in the collection:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$shuffled = $collection->shuffle();
$shuffled->all();
// [3, 2, 5, 1, 4] // (generated randomly)
```

For further methods and info you should check the laravel eloquent docs, there are methods almost for everything.

Cheers.

Comment: thank you for reply! thats good variant, but check another answer, theres an easier way)

Comment: You can always use fluent :), that's the way it is explained in Laravel docs. :)