# How to random an object coming from the database in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, random

Do you guys have any suggestions on how to random an object coming from the database? Example: I have an item table, inside the item table, I have (3) items. Then I requested an item which matches to the (3)items, and I only need to match (1)item out of those (3), using a random function..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row)

Comment: `$randomUser = DB::table('users')->where('whatever', $whatever)->inRandomOrder()->first();` It looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
$randomItem = Item::where('something, $something)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```