# stuck at DB query, laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need your help... 
Can't figure out where the problem is. 
I am trying to show all products of a subcategory.Sometimes it shows the first or the last record. Then it repeats many times the same record( as the cycle is).

```
category: id, name, visible

products:id, name, 

category_products:id, id_product, id_category
```

```
Route::get('navigation/{id}',function($id){
  $prods= \App\Products_to_Categories::where('id_category',$id)->get();
     $products=array();

    foreach ($prods as $prod)
    {
       $products[] = \App\Products::find($prod->id_product)->
                      where('visible','yes')
                     -> where('delete','no')->first();

    }


    return view('subcategories.order_products',
        ['products'=>$products ]);}
```

View blade

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                            <ul id="sortable">
                                @foreach($products as $product)
                                    <li class="ui-state-default" id="{{ $product->id}}"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span> {{$product->name}}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like products and categories are related through the join table category_products, so you can setup a `belongsToMany()` relationship and query from `Category` to `Product` without looping over the join table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Products::class, 'category_products', 'id_category', 'id_product');
}
```

Products model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Category::class, 'category_products', 'id_product', 'id_category');
}
```

Controller code:

```
$category = Category::find($id);
$products = $category->products()
                     ->where('visible', 'yes')
                     ->where('delete', 'no')
                     // ->inRandomOrder()   // un-comment this if you want results in random order
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Laravel >= 5.2: :

```
 $prods= \App\Products_to_Categories::where('id_category',$id)->get();
 $products=array();
 $whereIn = array();

 foreach ($prods as $prod)
 {
     $whereIn[] = $prod->id_product;
 }

 $products[] = \App\Products::find($prod->id_product)
                ->where('visible','yes')
                -> where('delete','no')
                ->whereIn('id', $whereIn)
                ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
                ->get();
```

This will give you the list of products of a specific category in random order.

Laravel 4.2.7 - 5.1:

```
User::orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
```

Laravel 4.0 - 4.2.6:

```
User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

Laravel 3:

```
User::order_by(DB::raw('RAND()'))->get();
```

source : 
[Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row)

Comment: Thank you ... but it shows property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: you have to make sure that you have the "id" property on your product model.

Comment: Instead of get(), i used first().... $products[] = \App\Products::find($prod->id_product)
                ->where('visible','yes')
                -> where('delete','no')
                ->whereIn('id', $whereIn)
                ->inRandomOrder()
                ->first(); but it shows me only one record (which isn't right, because it has to show me more than 1)

Comment: I just updated the example, try this : orderByRaw('RAND()')