# How to fetch random record using eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch random number of rows from table in laravel 5.7, but i could not find any solution.
I have use

```
 Model::all()->random(2);
```

It work fine. But i need to apply where clause with it like `Model::select('column')->where('column','value')->random(number of rows');`
So how can i achieve this using eloquent.
Please any suggestions for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row?rq=1

Comment: Simple Model::all()->random(1); will work for you

Comment: I have seen that but there is no where condition

Comment: I know that, but i need make it with where clause . like Modell::where('condition')->random(1);

Comment: Just to clarify, would you like to fetch a random row or a random number of rows?

Answer (score 13):

You can simply add to chain `inRandomOrder`, as suggested here:

[Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row)

And then limit your dataset.

```
Model::select('column')
    ->where('column','value')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(2) // here is yours limit
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much it work......

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`inRandomOrder`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) method in combination with `first`, like this: `Model::inRandomOrder()->select('column')->where('column','value')->first();`

Comment: I have tried it, but i return no row.

Comment: Then it sounds like your query doesn't have any results.

Comment: I try it again now it work thank you..

Comment: yes exactly..... that was the reason