# Laravel - Select five users at randon each day

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have three model classes: Userinfo, Winners, Participants

UserInfo
id, user_code, created_at

Winners
id, user_code, prize

Participants
id, user_code, prize

1. I want to select 5 user_code at random each day from UserInfo and save the into Winners. prize = winners, user_code will be the user_code from UserInfo
2. I want to select other 3 user_code at random each day from UserInfo and save the into Winners. prize = participants, user_code will be the user_code from UserInfo. But this three users here will be different from the five users in Winners.

How do I write Laravel code for this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Eloquent or Fluent random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a backend job which will repeat every day and use `Participants::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get()` method of eloquent for random users.
Check here about daily jobs:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Comment: How do I ensure that what is select for Winners is different from Participants

Comment: Select 5 random from participants.

Comment: for the next three Participants::whereNotIn('user_code', array('first five winner codes))->inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get()