# laravel database seeder adding add foreign key id randomly to seeds

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

I am trying to create seeders for testing purposes. I have users that belongs to a room via a room id, these rooms are created via a room seeder, in my users seeder, I create a user and update the room_id attribute like this,

```
factory(App\User::class, 150)->create([
        'host' => false,
        'room_id' =>  App\Room::inRandomOrder()->first()->id
    ]);
```

My problem is that all users generated here, all get the same room id, how can a truly get a random room id from the database and use it in my seeder?

Comment: App\Room::all()->random()->id Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row

Comment: You can use [rand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) to get a random id from the db.

Comment: @BigA not asking how to get random, I am asking why my random is not random but assiging the same ID to every user that is created, even though it has 30+ IDS to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with seeding. The problem is that, you are overriding the factory's default model attributes by passing an array of "values". You are passing the value of `App\Room::inRandomOrder()->first()->id` to the `create` method. So you would have all users with the same `room_id`.

To solve this issue, in laravel 8, you can move the `'room_id' => Room::inRandomOrder()->first()->id` to your `UsersFactory` definition:

```
class UsersFactory {
...

    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'room_id' => Room::inRandomOrder()->first()->id
        ];
    }
...
}
```

And create users like this,

```
App\User::factory()->count(150)->create([
    'host' => false
]);
```

In older version of laravel, define your factory as below:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker) use ($factory)  {
    return [
        'room_id' => Room::inRandomOrder()->first()->id
    ];
});
```

And create users like this,

```
factory(App\User::class, 150)->create([
        'host' => false,
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
App\Room::all()->random()->id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $users = factory(\App\User::class, 150)->create([
        'host' => false,
        'room_id' => $this->getRandomRoomId()
    ]);
}

private function getRandomRoomId() {
    $room = \App\Room::inRandomOrder()->first();
    return $room->id;
}
```

Try this one. It works for me. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: All 150 generated users have same room_id.

Comment: @udders Do you have more than 1 room in you database?

Comment: The first seeder that runs generates 30 rooms

Comment: @UtkarshRaval not really going to help me as I won't know the ID's before they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Also, make sure that you have multiple auto incremented room entries in the room table.

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function ($faker) use ($factory)  {
    return [
        'host' => false,
        'room_id' => $factory->create(App\Room::class)->id
    ];
});
```