# Create seeder for a table with two foreignkeys

Tags: laravel, migration, faker, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I was trying to create a seeder for Products table with two foreign keys (category_id and sub_category_id for categories and sub_categories tables respectively).

```
Category::all()->each(function ($category) {
        SubCategory::all()->each(function ($sub_category) {
            $faker = Faker::create();
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
                DB::table('products')->insert([
                    'product_name' => $faker->name,     
                    'product_description' =>  $faker->sentence,
                    'product_price' =>  rand(100, 1000),
                    'product_quantity' =>  rand(10,100),
                    'category_id' => $category->id,
                    'sub_category_id' =>  $sub_category->id,
                ]);
            }
        });
    });
```

Tried this but it's returning me an error of

> Undefined variable: category

I can create seeder with only the sub_category but I needed to create with category as well. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Create different seeder for all three tables. and then use [random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917558/laravel-eloquent-or-fluent-random-row) to fetch random category & random sub category & save that in product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, you are passing an anonymous function to the `each()` method. Anonymous functions don't have access to the variables outside of their scope.

You must pass the `$category` variable to the SubCategory's `each()` method this way:

```
Category::all()->each(function ($category) {
    SubCategory::all()->each(function ($sub_category) use ($category) {
        // now you have access to the $category
    });
});
```

As you can see I'm passing it by `use ($category)` to the function.

Comment: @MDB Good job bro 

Answer (score 0):

You are using a closure to go through `each` item in the `SubCategory` model. The initialisation of the `$category` variable is outside of the closure's scope. In order to access `$category` you need to make it available by using the `use` keyword:

```
SubCategory::all()->each(function ($sub_category) {...});
```

to

```
SubCategory::all()->each(function ($sub_category) use ($category) {...});
```